# Cannot find xApply function in R

Tags: r

I cannot find any documents in R about how to use xApply function. I got an assignment where it requires using xApply. 
Does it exist?
If yes, how is it used?

Thank you

Comment: There's this thing called [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=r%20xapply) you can try. I think that might be an approach that might catch on at some point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe "xApply" is referring to the general apply family which includes mapply, lapply, sapply, vapply ...

This is a good introduction to the apply functions.
https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/